# Sorting upcoming events listed in JSON

Tags: beginner, parsing, sorting, json, go

I've written my first program in GO, a command line tool that parses JSON  containing events from a file or from STDIN and outputs the upcoming events in sorted order. Please critique it!

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
    "github.com/urfave/cli"
    "strconv"
    "sort"
)

type Event struct {
    Occasion string `json:"occasion"`
    Invited_count int `json:"invited_count"`
    Year int `json:"year"`
    Month int `json:"month"`
    Day int `json:"day"`
}
func (e *Event) String() string {
    s := e.Occasion + "\n"
    s += strconv.Itoa(e.Year) + "-" + strconv.Itoa(e.Month) + "-" + strconv.Itoa(e.Day) + "\n"
    s += "Number Attending: " + strconv.Itoa(e.Invited_count)
    return s
}
type EventCollection struct {
    Events []Event `json:"events"`
}

type events Event
type By func(e1, e2 *Event) bool

func (by By) Sort(events []Event) {
    ps := &eventSorter{
        events: events,
        by:      by, // The Sort method's receiver is the function (closure) that defines the sort order.
    }
    sort.Sort(ps)
}

// eventSorter joins a By function and a slice of Events to be sorted.
type eventSorter struct {
    events []Event
    by      func(e1, e2 *Event) bool // Closure used in the Less method.
}

// Len is part of sort.Interface.
func (s *eventSorter) Len() int {
    return len(s.events)
}
// Less is part of sort.Interface. It is implemented by calling the "by" closure in the sorter.
func (s *eventSorter) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return s.by(&s.events[i], &s.events[j])
}

// Swap is part of sort.Interface.
func (s *eventSorter) Swap(i, j int) {
    s.events[i], s.events[j] = s.events[j], s.events[i]
}
func main() {
    app := cli.NewApp()
    app.Name = "Next Event"
    app.Usage = "Find out the next event on your calendar!"
    app.Flags = []cli.Flag{
    cli.StringFlag{
        Name:  "config, c",
        Usage: "Load JSON events from `FILE`",
        },
    }
    app.Action = func(c *cli.Context) error {
        p := fmt.Println

        p("Hello friend!")
        // read events json from config
        b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(c.String("config")) // just pass the file name
        if c.String("config") != "" && err !=nil {
            p(err)
            return nil
        }
        // if no config, then read from STDIN
        if c.String("config") == "" {
            b, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)
            if string(b) == "" {
                if err != nil {
                    p(err)
                    return nil
                }
                }
        }


        events := new(EventCollection)
        err = json.Unmarshal(b, &events)  // parse json and store in events var
        if err != nil {
            p(err)
            return nil
        }


        var times []Event
        times = make([]Event, len(events.Events))
        var eventTime string
        var t1 time.Time
        var i int
        i = 0
        // filter events before the current date
        for _, event := range events.Events {
            eventTime  = strconv.Itoa(event.Year) + "-" + strconv.Itoa(event.Month) + "-" + strconv.Itoa(event.Day)

            t1, err = time.Parse("2006-1-2", eventTime)
            if time.Now().Before(t1) {
                times[i] = event
                i += 1
            }
        }
        p("Upcoming Events: ")
        var t2 time.Time
        date := func(e1, e2 *Event) bool{
            eventTime = strconv.Itoa(e1.Year) + "-" + strconv.Itoa(e1.Month) + "-" + strconv.Itoa(e1.Day)
            t1, err = time.Parse("2006-1-2", eventTime)
            eventTime = strconv.Itoa(e2.Year) + "-" + strconv.Itoa(e2.Month) + "-" + strconv.Itoa(e2.Day)
            t2, err = time.Parse("2006-1-2", eventTime)
            return t1.Before(t2)
        }
        // sort the upcoming events
        By(date).Sort(times[:i])
        for _, time := range times[:i] {
            p(time.String())
            p()
        }
        if err != nil {
            p("Invalid Event Date", err)
            return nil
        }


        return nil
    }

    app.Run(os.Args)
}
```

Here is a sample of the JSON it will parse:

```
{
"events": [
  {
    "occasion": "Birthday party",
    "invited_count": 120,
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 2,
    "day": 14
  },
  {
    "occasion": "Technical discussion",
    "invited_count": 23,
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 11,
    "day": 24
  },
  {
    "occasion": "Press release",
    "invited_count": 64,
    "year": 2015,
    "month": 12,
    "day": 17,
    "cancelled": true
  },
  {
    "occasion": "New year party",
    "invited_count": 55,
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 1,
    "day": 1
  },
  {
    "occasion": "Friendsgiving Party",
    "invited_count": 45,
    "year": 2016,
    "month": 11,
    "day": 22

  }
]
}
```